# Solving 935B - Fafa and the Gates in Codeforces

Tags: c++

I have a question about 935B - Fafa and the Gates in CodeForces. My code is working for the first test cases but it’s getting stuck on test case 20, this is the code I used, could someone please tell me what I’m doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    long long a, x = 0, y = 0, total = 0;
    cin >> a;
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    for (long long i = 0; i <= a; i++){
        if (s[i] == 'U') x += 1;
        if (s[i] == 'R') y += 1;
        if (x == y && s[i] == s[i+1]) total += 1;
    }
    cout << total << endl;
}
```

Comment: Given that *a* is meant to be the length of *s*, it looks like you're going well past the end of the string in your loop, which is incorrect.

Comment: How would I fix this problem and why would it then work for the first test cases lol?

Comment: It's undefined behavior.  The program is allowed to do literally anything, including appearing to work like you expected.

Comment: I don't know what the original question is, but `for (long long i = 0; i <= a; i++)` looks suspicious.  Why is it `i<=a` instead of `i<a` ?

Comment: oh wow thanks so much - no idea why it worked for the other cases though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the `i<=a` issue I called out in the comments above, there's another issue.

Even if you fix the for loop to be stop after `i<a`, then this statement:

```
if (x == y && s[i] == s[i+1]) total += 1;
```

Will still reference an invalid index at `s[i+1]` since `i+1` is an invalid index on the last iteration of the array.

On each iteration of the loop, you need to see if he's at the gate first, then update `x` or `y` appropriately, then assess if he changed kingdoms.

If he's at a position `x > y`, you know he's in the lower kingdom. Likewise if `y > x`, you know he's in the upper kingdom on the map.

I think this is closer to what you want:

```
bool topKingdom = false;  // initially at 0,0.  Fafa is currently in the "lower kingdom" on the map

for (long long i = 0; i < a; i++){

    bool atGate = (x == y);

    if (s[i] == 'U') y++;
    if (s[i] == 'R') x++;

    // if we were previously "at a gate", assess if we are now in a new kingdom from before
    if (atGate && !topKingdom && y > x) {
        topKingdom = true;
        total++;
    }
    else if (atGate && topKingdom && x > y) {
       topKingdom = false;
       total++;    
    }
}
cout << total << endl;
```